# statement not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using this class code to insert data into the database:

```
<?php

Class User
{
  private $error = "";
  public  function signup($post)
  {
    $data = array();

    $data['name']    = trim($_POST['name']);
    $data['email']   = trim($_POST['email']);
    $data['pass']    = trim($_POST['pass']);
    $pass2           = trim($_POST['pass2']);

    if(empty($data['email']) || !preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+.[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$/", $data['email']))
    {
      $this->error .= "Please enter a valid Email <br>";
    }
    if(empty($data['name']) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $data['name']))
    {
      $this->error .= "Please enter a valid Name <br>";
    }

    if($data['pass'] !== $pass2)
    {
      $this->error .= "Password dont match <br>";
    }

    if(strlen($data['pass']) < 4)
    {
      $this->error .= "Password must be at least 4 character long <br>";
    }

    if($this->error == "")
    {
      $data['rank'] = "customer";
      $data['url_address'] = $this->get_random_string_max(60);
      $data['date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      $query  = "INSERT INTO users (url_address, name, email, pass, date, rank) VALUES (:url_address, :name, :email, :pass, :date, :rank)";
      $db     = Database::getInstance();
      $result = $db->write($query, $data);

      if ($result) {
        header("Location:" . ROOT . "login");
        die();
      }
    }
  }

  private function get_random_string_max($length)
  {
    $array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
    $text = "";

    $length = rand(4, $length);
    for ($i=0; $i>$length;$i++) {
      $random = rand(0, 61);
      $text .= $array[$random];
    }
    return $text;
  }
}
```

this is the database Class:

```
<?php

Class Database
{
  public static $con;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $dsn = 'mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname='. DB_NAME;
    $options = array(
      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    try {
      return $db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if(self::$con) {
      return self::$con;
    }
    return $instance = new self();
  }

  public function read($query, $data = array())
  {
    $stmt = self::$con->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->excute($data);
    if ($result) {
      $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      if(is_array($data)) {
        return $data;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function write($query, $data = array())
  {
    $stmt = self::$con->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->excute($data);
    if ($result) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I'm using MVC and this is the signup controller page and database class.

pass2 is retyped password in the form.

but the data not inserting into the database and not redirecting to the login page.

and
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

not showing any errors.

what is the problem?

Comment: Does `Database::write()` check for errors?

Comment: If `$stmt->execute($data)` returns false you should report the error so you can fix the problem.

Comment: No, This is the function

`public function write($query, $data = array())
  {
    $stmt = self::$con->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->excute($data);
    if ($result) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }`

Comment: You should enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: I edited my question and put the database class, the PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION is on and not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Database Class You have an error in writing the function **excute()** in line:

```
$result = $stmt->excute($data);
```

it should be **execute()**

```
$result = $stmt->execute($data);
```